# how does fix the error of "no packages specified problem" for compiling package in r?

Tags: r

I tried to install a package in R on the server. it recompiled from sources to install package but I see the following error:

'\pn-s\proj1\p_k\fsh'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.
Error: ERROR: no packages specified

the above path is my workspace that my package is in it.
Do you know how I can fix this problem?